# Two timers in one page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ironspeed

I have two timers in one page but second timer is not working.

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>

<asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="Timer2_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblcurrenttime5.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}       

protected void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label6.Text = "Timer 2 is working";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?  What's the question? ??

Comment: lblcurrenttime5.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();  Is working and updating every 1 second                                        label6.Text = "Timer 2 is working"; is not updating

Comment: i found that 1 second  working for both  5 seconds not working

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code you want in the pageLoad method

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      lblcurrenttime5.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
      label6.Text = "Timer 2 is working";
    }
```

Since the page refreshes with the timer, it will pass through the pageload method.

Comment: Make sure that the elements being updated (Labels along with the timers) are inside the <ContentTemplate> tag which is inside <UpdatePanel> tag right under the <ScriptManager> tag.